# HTTP backend software for generating canonical, strictly, monotonically, increasing project specific (build-)numbers for software builds

Tags: open-source, web-apps, web-services, version-control

I'm maintaining a couple of software projects for embedded devices and respective firmware images are being built on different machines.
It's important that each build contains a build number which is larger (ideally +1) than the last build (on whichever machine that build was triggered).

I'm looking for an open-source software which runs as an HTTP backend to which I can pass at least a project's name and receive project's specific build number which is strictly monotonically increasing, which I can then embed into my software builds during compilation.

My demands are simple enough to code such thing by myself, however I'd prefer to avoid having yet another (even though probably very small) side project to maintain.